# Question on reasoning . . .

Tags: logic, puzzle

George is younger brother of Michael. 
Michael asked George a question of a seven digit number: 
-   The number of zeroes in the number gives the first digit of the number. 
-   The number of ones in the number gives the second digit of the number. 
-   The third digit of the number is the number of twos in the number and so on. 
Can you help George  guess this interesting number?

Comment: is the first digit the one on the right or the one on the left?

Comment: Side note: this is a very low-quality question. First of all, because you have not shown any effort to answer it on your own. Second, what relevance does the fact that "George is younger brother of Michael" have to the question at hand??? It just makes it look even more like a copy-paste from your homework assignment or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

The number cannot have leading zeroes, because then we'd immediately have a contradiction.

The number cannot start with $7$ or more, because we don't have that many digits.

The number cannot start with $6$.  All other digits must be zero, but the last digit has to be nonzero, a contradiction.

The number cannot start with $5$.  We need five zeroes.  If we make the second to last digit a $1$, then we must make the second digit a $1$, but now we have less than five zeroes, a contradiction.

The number cannot start with $4$.  If we make the fifth digit a $1$, then we have to make the second digit a $1$.  But now we have two $1$s, and need to change another digit, but we can't, because we need four zeroes.

What about $3$?  Make the fourth digit $1$.  We now have a $1$, so we make the second digit $1$.  But now we have two $1$s.  We can make the second digit a $2$, and increment the third digit so it's a $1$, and everything still works!

What about $1$ or $2$ at the start?  This limits the number of zeros we can put in the number, and we find quickly that we run out of room if we fill in a lot of spaces with stuff other than zero.

Comment: +1.  Gives reasoning for Carser's somewhat terse answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$3211000$$ has 3 zeros, 2 ones, 1 two, and 1 three.

Comment: I feel like an explanation would be nice for the OP.

Comment: @IanLimarta What part do you think he doesn't understand?